# How to mount encrypted APK expansion files?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I tried to mount expansion files this way:

```
    final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
    String obbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb";
    final String obbFilePath = obbPath + "/com.example/main.1.com.example.obb";
    storageManager.mountObb(obbFilePath, "SecretKey", new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
            super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
            if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                onObbMounted();
            } else {
                Log.d("##", "Path: " + path + "; state: " + state);
            }
        }
    });
```

But in runtime I'm getting state 21: ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT:

```
Path: /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/com.example/main.1.com.example.obb; state: 21
```

I've added this:

```
    File f = new File(obbFilePath);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        Log.e("OBB", "FILE NOT FOUND!!!");
    }
```

And logcat says that file exist. I have no idea, why I can get this state 21?

Comment: Well, I haven't found how to mount encrypted obb file, but using non-encrypted obb works fine.

Comment: hello uncle Lem, Here i am facing same state-21, so please give me an example how can i using non-encrypted obb

Comment: @KrunalShah I created util class to manage obb, please see https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/io/github/unclelem/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java You can also find some details in my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685315/how-to-create-obb-files-using-jobb-tool-android/14687592#14687592

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and i figured aout that many times `Error 21` is casued by Linux Files Permissions over the obb, and the problem is that Android cannot have access to it so the `StorageManager` launches `Error 21`. When you create the .obb file, change permissions and user group to the file, something like:

```
$chmod 664 <obb-filename>.obb    
$chown user:group <obb-filename>.obb
```

Then try again, worked for me.

Comment: In this case `user` and `group` are generic , you have to try with any valid user of your Linux instalation where youre trying to build with the AOSP files.