# How to create OBB files USING jobb tool Android

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

My app has grown to be over 50mb, so I now need to use an expansion file. On searching I came to know that there are different files that can be used as expansion files such as zip, pdf etc. I am trying to put my data in .obb files but I don't know how to create these files and put the data in these files.

**Updated**
**First:**

I found out that `jobb` tool is used to create obb files. But I am confused how this `$ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11` command is run.
I tried to run this `($ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11` on cmd but my cmd saying jobb is not recognise as internal or external command.

**Second:**
Which type of files can I put in these obb files? I am thinking layouts, drawable files?

Comment: Make sure the directory where jobb is stored is in your PATH (or give the full name on the command line).

Comment: yah there is no jobb tool. So from where i can install it??

Comment: It is part of the Android SDK, and found in the SDK directory in `tools/jobb`

Comment: ok i installed latest eclipse but in sdk manager tools there is no jobb tool

Comment: In the SDK manager at the top of the window look what it says for `SDK Path:`. Append `tools` to it and look into this directory.

Comment: yah i look in this directory but there is no jobb tool directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23895/discussion-between-akhter-and-henry)

Comment: "there is no jobb tool directory" it's not directory, it's just bat. Try to reinstall Android SDK, it worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> my cmd saying jobb is not recognise as internal or external command

Add /tools to your path or instead of `jobb` use `path/to/sdk/tools/jobb.bat`

> which type of files are put in these obb files

Big ones. Like drawables, sounds etc. Then, for example, you can use this code to put drawable file into ImageView:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
        sm.getMountedObbPath("/path/to/obb/file") + 
        "path/to/file/in/obb.png")
```

or, play sound:

```
mp.setDataSource(AcItem.this, 
    Uri.fromFile(new File(
        sm.getMountedObbPath("/path/to/obb/file") + 
        "path/to/file/in/obb.png"));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

As I promised, GitHub link to my obb manager class: https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/io/github/unclelem/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java
I hope it would help.

Comment: thankyou for the great help.. one thing i want to ask is that from where jobb.bat can be download? there is path to tools in SDK but there is no jobb.bat file in tools folder

Comment: @Akhter make sure that you've been installed latest Android SDK and Android SDK Platform-tools (I have rev. 21.0.1 and 16.0.1, respectively). I had same problem and I solved it by downloading latest SDK, deleting old one and installing new one - may be it's not the simplest way to fix that problem, but it worked for me.

Comment: hi! i found obbListner in the provided link with which it should be initilize??

Comment: you should create it in your activity, implement methods for UI update in different cases (e.g. onFilesNotFound means that you have to start download, and onMountSucceess - that mount is finished succesfully) and put it in createNewInstance() method. Then, when you'll need to get file from obb just use getInstance() to get an existing instance

Comment: hi uncle lem, i got an issue with your code on github. i keep having error state 21 when mounting the obb. can u help me?

Comment: I had this error with mounting encrypted obb files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342068/how-to-mount-encrypted-apk-expansion-files

Comment: @SanketKachhela Use the [JOBB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html), Luke! ;)

Comment: @uncleLem Your GitHub link says Page Not Found

Comment: @Nitish sorry, old link. Here it is: https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/io/github/unclelem/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java

Comment: after i create obb file from assets , can i delete all assets?

Answer (score 3):

Just write Like this in command prompt and press enter

```
C:\>C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools\jobb -d C:\
Myworkspace\ImageTargets\assets\ -o Imagetargets.obb -k globe -pn com.ib.globeap
p.activity -pv 200 -v
```

Comment: where can i find output file (file obb)